# JSOM CSOM query only get dates that are not passed todays date

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, custom-list

I have a list which contains an end date, I want to query this list and only collect the items which end date have not passed todays date. Once this has happened I want to count the new queried table.
Here is my code, this does not work.

```
function retrieveCurrentListProperties() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Urgent Alerts");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var q =  "<View><Query><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='End_x0020_Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'><Today /></Value></Leq></Where></Query></View>";
    camlQuery.ViewXml(q);
    this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(this.listItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCListItemsLoadSuccess), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onCListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {

    var count = 0;
    var listEnumerator = this.listItems.getEnumerator();
    //iterate though all of the items

count = this.listItems.get_count();
var allAlerts = document.getElementById('allAlerts');
allAlerts.innerHTML = 'Total Alerts : ' +count;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CAML Query, you need to set the view XML as:

```
 camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
```

Comment: if I replace ViewXml with set_viewXml I get the error `request failed one or more field types are not installed properly. go to the list settings to delete these fields undefined`

Comment: The FieldRef you're using 'End_x0020_Date' is that the correct one? Try replacing that with '_EndDate' if you're using OOTB fields.

Comment: I named the field `'End Date'` which didn't work, so I've been trying numerous ways to include the space in the search

Comment: Did you try "_EndDate" ?

Comment: That gives me the same error as before

Comment: Fixed it, for some reason it wasn't refreshing I used `_x0020_` at it worked with ` camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);`

Comment: Go to List settings page, hover over the 'End Date' column, copy the link. See what's the name at the end of the URL.

Comment: glad that you were able to resolve it.